# Call new activity from Webview

Tags: android-intent

I want to call a activity from a webview

The app crashes ... but it works form a activity to a an others without webview

What point I am missing?

Thank you.

public class AndroidInterface extends Activity{
    Context mContext;

```
AndroidInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public void newactivity(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, App2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    public void showToast(String toast) {

    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

through javascript I can only call a toast but not a activiy...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Java code from WebView. For example see here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

Comment: Thank you for reply ... your link show how to call a toast  or a dialog from javascript. what I really need is to call a new activity instead of a toast or a dialog from javascript thank you